# Antlr pattern matching and lexer modes

Tags: java, antlr4

I am trying to compile a pattern for [html grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/html). The code below shows how to parse a string containing `htmlAttributeRule`:

```
String code = "href=\"val\"";
CharStream chars = CharStreams.fromString(code);
Lexer lexer = new HTMLLexer(chars);
lexer.pushMode(HTMLLexer.TAG);
TokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
HTMLParser parser = new HTMLParser(tokens);
parser.htmlAttribute();
```

But when i'm trying to:

```
ParseTreePatternMatcher matcher = new ParseTreePatternMatcher(lexer, parser);
matcher.compile(code, HTMLParser.RULE_htmlAttribute);
```

it fails with error:

```
line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'href="val"'

org.antlr.v4.runtime.NoViableAltException
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.noViableAlt(ParserATNSimulator.java:2026)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.execATN(ParserATNSimulator.java:467)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.adaptivePredict(ParserATNSimulator.java:393)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserInterpreter.visitDecisionState(ParserInterpreter.java:316)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserInterpreter.visitState(ParserInterpreter.java:223)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserInterpreter.parse(ParserInterpreter.java:194)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.pattern.ParseTreePatternMatcher.compile(ParseTreePatternMatcher.java:205)
```

When i tried to:

```
List<? extends Token> tokenList = matcher.tokenize(code);
```

The result contained a single token, the same as when using the lexer with `DEFAULT_MODE`. Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the following code from `ParseTreePatternMatcher::tokenize`:

```
TextChunk textChunk = (TextChunk)chunk;
ANTLRInputStream in = new ANTLRInputStream(textChunk.getText());
lexer.setInputStream(in);
Token t = lexer.nextToken();
```

`Lexer::setInputStream` clears `_modeStack` and sets `_mode` to `0`. One possible solution is to extend `ParseTreePatternMatcher`, override method `tokenize` and insert `lexer.pushMode(lexerMode)` after `lexer.setInputStream(in)`:

```
TextChunk textChunk = (TextChunk)chunk;
ANTLRInputStream in = new ANTLRInputStream(textChunk.getText());
lexer.setInputStream(in);
lexer.pushMode(lexerMode);
Token t = lexer.nextToken();
```

But method `tokenize` uses `Chunk` and `TextChunk` which cannot be accesses from outsize package, so we are obligated to define the extension class in the same package as `ParseTreePatternMatcher`.

Another solution i'm considering is to modify byte code of the method using ASM.